# Android studio not cleaning dependencies after Gradle clean

Tags: java, android, gradle, deeplearning4j

I am trying to use deeplearning4j on Android device, switching between debugging on emulator and physical device.
For this I have multiple dependencies that are of a huge size and are all necessary. Thankfully, there is an implementation for each platform provided by `org.bytedeco`.

So targeting Android arm-64 which are the most common I omited other platforms like

```
//    implementation group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native', version: '1.0.0-beta6', classifier: "android-x86_64" //for emulator
```

.

Wanted dependencies are like:

```
implementation (group: 'org.deeplearning4j', name: 'deeplearning4j-core', version: '1.0.0-beta7') {
    exclude group: 'org.bytedeco', module: 'opencv-platform'
    exclude group: 'org.bytedeco', module: 'leptonica-platform'
    exclude group: 'org.bytedeco', module: 'hdf5-platform'
}
implementation group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native', version: '1.0.0-beta7'
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.9-1.5.3'
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'opencv', version: '4.3.0-1.5.3'
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'leptonica', version: '1.79.0-1.5.3' 

implementation group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native', version: '1.0.0-beta7', classifier: "android-arm64"
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.9-1.5.3', classifier: "android-arm64"
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'opencv', version: '4.3.0-1.5.3', classifier: "android-arm64"
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'leptonica', version: '1.79.0-1.5.3', classifier: "android-arm64"
```

The problem is, when I build or clean and build the output Jar is huge, it is more than 800 mb, and if I see the tree of dependencies, I always see other platforms jars in path like:

[image]

I know that not all of these are necessary, because at one point in time (and I couldn't reproduce what was present and what I aim for again) I had not all of these dependencies. The exported APK was around 400 mb.

So what's up with the Windows, Linux, dependencies...

**Sync project and Gradle clean Gradle build do nothing to these, exporting APK as well. Always an APK of > 800mb**

Edit:

*Please do not pay attention to versions mismatch between different dependencies and API and implementations. I am switching between versions dl4j beta6, dl4j  beta7 and others*

Comment: You're going to get that if you depend on -platform dependencies. Make sure to exclude anything that ends with -platform. There is also an easy way to manipulate those with Gradle JavaCPP: https://github.com/bytedeco/gradle-javacpp#the-platform-plugin

Comment: What are platform dependencies here? Isn't the classifier keyword here to specify exactly the platform. Thanks

Comment: That was the solution, from 800 mb to 200. Thanks

Comment: Yes, the classifier is used for that, but the artifacts that end with "-platform" contain dependencies to all of them.